# What is derivative of one conditional function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$
F(x) = \cases{x& if $x>\lambda$\\
       0& if $x<\lambda$}
$$
What is partial derivative of $f(x, lambda)$ with respect to $\lambda$?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x, \lambda) = \cdots$?

Comment: yes i want to calculate derivative of f(x, lambda) with respect to lambda

Comment: What you are writing is that you want derivative of one variable function with respect to other variable, which is 0 everywhere.

Comment: Do you mean the partial derivative?  Why isn't $F$ written as a function of $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes i mean partial derivative with respect to lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x,\lambda) = \cases{x& if $x>\lambda$\\
       0& if $x<\lambda$}$$

$$ \frac {\partial f}{\partial \lambda } =0 \text { if } x\ne \lambda$$

$$ \frac {\partial f}{\partial \lambda } = \text {  does not exist,  if } x= \lambda$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It should be written like that: $f(x, \lambda)=\frac{x+xsgn(x-\lambda)}{2}$.

Also note that derivative of sign function is twice Dirac delta.

Comment: And what if I replace lambda with some other variable z